# Extract text form NSString using key words

Tags: ios

I have an NSString that when NSlogged returns this:

```
device status: (SOME LETTERS), session code: (SOME NUMBERS)
```

how can I extract the two from the initial string without actually cutting the string to have something like:

```
NSString* str1 = text for "device status";
NSString* str1 = text for "session code";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make friends with [NSRegularExpression](https://www.google.ie/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html&ei=ejRhUumMC8Xm7Aa9jYDYDw&usg=AFQjCNEL6_EXLwjPTgWUPgZdI08Ik1xvmg&sig2=_FtLCXbICfjinmet22jBnQ&bvm=bv.54934254,d.ZGU):

```
NSString* str = @"device status: dead, session code: 666";

NSError *err;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"device status: (//w*), session code: (//d*)" options:0 error:&err];
if (err) {
    NSLog(@"Returned an error: %@", [err localizedDescription]);
}
NSArray* matches = [regex matchesInString:str options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [str length])];
//  get the first match
NSTextCheckingResult *match = matches[0];

// extract the groups
NSString *deviceStatus = [str substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:1]];
NSString *sessionCode = [str substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:2]];
```

Comment: Even if the other suggested methods are much shorter, I tick this as accepted because it was exactly the approach I was looking for :) thanks

Comment: This code is causing a crash though, at NSTextCheckingResult *match = matches[0];

Comment: Means there are no matches, I suggest you play with http://regexpal.com to see if you have formed your regex pattern properly.

Comment: Oh I know where the problem was, there was not space between the colon and 666 in the _str_. Note that I wrote this from memory, it's more like a pseudo code than the real thing, some caution needs to be taken before transplanting this into your system.

Answer (score 3):

Simple Code will be like.

As You can use [componentsSeparatedByString](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/componentsSeparatedByString%3a)

```
- (NSArray *)componentsSeparatedByString:(NSString *)separator
```

means Returns an array containing substrings from the receiver that have been divided by a given separator.

```
NSString *string = @"device status: (SOME LETTERS), session code: (SOME NUMBERS)";
NSArray *array = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
NSArray *one = [[array objectAtIndex:0] componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
NSArray *two = [[array objectAtIndex:1] componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];

NSLog(@"key = %@ and Value = %@",[one objectAtIndex:0],[one objectAtIndex:1]);
NSLog(@"key = %@ and Value = %@",[two objectAtIndex:0],[two objectAtIndex:1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *commaSeparated = [originalString componentsSeparatedByString:@", "];
NSArray *colonSeparated1 = [commaSeparated[0] componentsSeparatedByString:@": ";
NSArray *colonSeparated2 = [commaSeparated[1] componentsSeparatedByString:@": ";
NSString *statusString = colonSeparated1[1];
NSString *sessionString = colonSeparated2[1];
```